# R data format : yyyy-mm-dd hh mm ss to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: r

I want to convert yyyy-mm-dd am hh:mm:ss into yyyy-mm-dd

mydata$date => 2021-04-10 pm 4:48:32 and typeof date is character

Any Suggestion?

I used format function but no luck

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as.Date` with the following syntax

```
mydata$date <- as.Date(mydata$date, format = '%Y-%m-%d %p %H:%M:%S')
```

### Output

```
[1] "2021-04-10"
```

More info here about the formatting options.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime